# Refreshing a mounted volume on Docker periodically

Tags: docker, docker-volume, fileshare

So I have a docker container up which needs to access a few Shared drive on Windows. These mounts keep expiring after some time and we need to restart the docker containers to make sure we have them mounted again.

```
volumes:
  shared-drive:
          driver: local
          driver_opts:
              type: cifs
              o: username=user,password=password,domain=xx
              device: "\\\\xx.xx.xxx.xxx\\path$$"
```

How do I refresh these volumes periodically?